# How to read request body from Middleware in NET 6 C# (WEB API)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, middleware, httpcontext

I have a middleware, where I catch the errors and I want to print the route and the information sent in the body, I use several displayed codes but the information returned is empty.

this is the middleware I use to catch errors that may occur in my source code, what I do is catch the error and print the stack.

```
using System.Net.Mime;
using System.Net;
using System.Transactions;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace MyWebApi.Middlewares
{
    public static class MyCustomMiddlewareExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseMyCustomMiddleware(
            this IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.UseMiddleware<MyCustomMiddleware>();
        }
    }

    public class MyCustomMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        private readonly ILogger<MyCustomMiddleware> _logger;

        public MyCustomMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<MyCustomMiddleware> logger)
        {
            _next = next;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                await _next(context);
                if (context.Response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                    throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError("({errorCode})Message Error: {ex}\r\nqueryString/Body:{queryString}", "500", ex, await GetInfo(context));
            }
        }

        private async Task<string> GetInfo(HttpContext context)
        {
            var request = context.Request;
            string result = string.Empty;
            if (request.Method == HttpMethods.Post && request.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                request.EnableBuffering();
                request.Body.Position = 0;
                var buffer = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(request.ContentLength)];
                await request.BodyReader.ReadAsync();
                //get body string here...
                var requestContent = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);

                request.Body.Position = 0;
                result = string.Concat('[', request.Method, "]: ", request.Path, '/', request.QueryString, "\r\nBody: ", requestContent);
            }
            else
            {
                result = string.Concat('[', request.Method, "]: ", request.Path, '/', request.QueryString);
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs:

```
var app = builder.Build();

//Middlewares
app.UseMyCustomMiddleware();
```

in my controller:

```
namespace MyWebApi.Controllers.V4
{
    [ApiController]
    [EnableCors("cors")]
    [Authorize]
    [Route("v{version:apiVersion}/Products")]
    [ApiVersion("4.0")]
    public class ProductsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        private readonly IproductsBusinessLogic _productsBusinessLogic;
        private readonly IValidator<ProductsRequestDto> _ProductsRequestDtoValidator;
        private readonly ILogger<ProductsController> _logger;
        public ProductsController(
            ILogger<ProductsController> logger,
            IConfiguration configuration,
            IproductsBusinessLogic productsBusinessLogic,
            IValidator<ProductsRequestDto> ProductsRequestDtoValidator
            )
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _configuration = configuration;
            _productsBusinessLogic = productsBusinessLogic;
            _ProductsRequestDtoValidator = ProductsRequestDtoValidator;
        }

        [MapToApiVersion("4.0")]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromBody] ProductsRequestDto request)
        {
            var results = await _ProductsRequestDtoValidator.ValidateAsync(request);
            results.AddToModelState(ModelState, null);
            if (!results.IsValid)
            {
                return new ValidationFailedResult(results);
            }
            var result = await _productsBusinessLogic.Register(request);
            return Ok(result);
        }
    }
}
```

in the log is printed out:

> queryString/Body:[POST]: /v4.0/Products/ Body: |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution in this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/request-response?view=aspnetcore-7.0#pipelines

I now use BodyReader, in the end my code ended up like this:

```
using System.Net.Mime;
using System.Net;
using System.Transactions;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace MyWebApi.Middlewares
{
    public static class MyCustomMiddlewareExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseMyCustomMiddleware(
            this IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.UseMiddleware<MyCustomMiddleware>();
        }
    }

    public class MyCustomMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        private readonly ILogger<MyCustomMiddleware> _logger;

        public MyCustomMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<MyCustomMiddleware> logger)
        {
            _next = next;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                await _next(context);
                if (context.Response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                    throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError("({errorCode})Message Error: {ex}\r\nqueryString/Body:{queryString}", "500", ex, await GetInfo(context));
            }
        }

        private async Task<string> GetInfo(HttpContext context)
        {
            var request = context.Request;
            string strInfoBody = string.Empty;
            bool infoBody = request.ContentLength > 0;
            if (infoBody)
            {
                request.EnableBuffering();
                request.Body.Position = 0;
                List<string> tmp = await GetListOfStringFromPipe(request.BodyReader);
                request.Body.Position = 0;

                strInfoBody = string.Concat("\r\nBody: ", string.Join("", tmp.ToArray()));
            }

            return string.Concat('[', request.Method, "]: ", request.Path, '/', request.QueryString,(infoBody ? strInfoBody : string.Empty));
        }
        
        private async Task<List<string>> GetListOfStringFromPipe(PipeReader reader)
        {
            List<string> results = new List<string>();

            while (true)
            {
                ReadResult readResult = await reader.ReadAsync();
                var buffer = readResult.Buffer;

                SequencePosition? position = null;

                do
                {
                    // Look for a EOL in the buffer
                    position = buffer.PositionOf((byte)'\n');

                    if (position != null)
                    {
                        var readOnlySequence = buffer.Slice(0, position.Value);
                        AddStringToList(results, in readOnlySequence);

                        // Skip the line + the \n character (basically position)
                        buffer = buffer.Slice(buffer.GetPosition(1, position.Value));
                    }
                }
                while (position != null);


                if (readResult.IsCompleted && buffer.Length > 0)
                {
                    AddStringToList(results, in buffer);
                }

                reader.AdvanceTo(buffer.Start, buffer.End);

                // At this point, buffer will be updated to point one byte after the last
                // \n character.
                if (readResult.IsCompleted)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            return results;
        }

        private static void AddStringToList(List<string> results, in ReadOnlySequence<byte> readOnlySequence)
        {
            // Separate method because Span/ReadOnlySpan cannot be used in async methods
            ReadOnlySpan<byte> span = readOnlySequence.IsSingleSegment ? readOnlySequence.First.Span : readOnlySequence.ToArray().AsSpan();
            results.Add(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(span));
        }
    }
}
```

in Program.cs, before invoking the use of middleware:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) => {
    context.Request.EnableBuffering();
    await next();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You are almost there:

```
var requestContent = "";
request.EnableBuffering();
using (var reader = new StreamReader(request.Body, Encoding.UTF8, true, 1024, true))
{
    requestContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
request.Body.Position = 0;
```

Comment: request.EnableRewind() does not work for net 6

Comment: ouch, that's right, that was pre 3.0, will edit

Answer (score 1):

> I want to print the route and the information sent in the body, I use
> several displayed codes but the information returned is empty.

As [request.Body](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/request-response?view=aspnetcore-7.0#stream-examples) is the type of [stream class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream?view=net-7.0) thus, we can use [StreamReder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=net-7.0) to extract the request body which could return us the expected results as well.

Let's examine that in practice:

Custom Request Reader Model:

```
public class RequstBodyReaderModel
        {
            public string? HttpVerb { get; set; }
            public string? RequestPath { get; set; }
            public string? RequestRawData { get; set; }
            public string? Message { get; set; }
        }
```

**Note:** For demonstrating the sample I am using above class to bind my request body.

Request Body Reader Middleware:

```
public class ReadRequestBodyMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        public ReadRequestBodyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }
        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            var request = context.Request;
            var stream = request.Body;// At the begining it holding original request stream                    
            var originalReader = new StreamReader(stream);
            var originalContent = await originalReader.ReadToEndAsync(); // Reading first request

            //My Custom Response Class
            var readingRequestBody = new RequstBodyReaderModel();
            readingRequestBody.HttpVerb = request.Method;
            readingRequestBody.RequestPath = request.Path;
            readingRequestBody.RequestRawData = originalContent;
            readingRequestBody.Message = "Here I am Reading the request body";

            //converting my custom response class to jsontype
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(readingRequestBody);
            //Modifying existing stream
            var requestData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
            stream = new MemoryStream(requestData);
            request.Body = stream;
            await _next(context);
           
        }

        
    }
```

**Note:** You can keep the existing request body, for the test I am rebinding with the modified value in [request.Body = stream;](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=net-7.0#constructors) but you can customize as per your needs.

Calling Middleware In Program.cs:

```
app.UseMiddleware<ReadRequestBodyMiddleware>();
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in  https://medium.com/@luisalexandre.rodrigues/logging-http-request-and-response-in-net-web-api-268135dcb27b

```
private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
private readonly ILogger<LoggingMiddleware> _logger;

public LoggingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<LoggingMiddleware> logger)
{
    _next = next;
    _logger = logger;
}

public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    await LogRequest(context);

    var originalResponseBody = context.Response.Body;

    using (var responseBody = new MemoryStream())
    {
        context.Response.Body = responseBody;
        await _next.Invoke(context);
        
        await LogResponse(context, responseBody, originalResponseBody);
    }
}

private async Task LogResponse(HttpContext context, MemoryStream responseBody, Stream originalResponseBody)
{
    var responseContent = new StringBuilder();
    responseContent.AppendLine("=== Response Info ===");
    
    responseContent.AppendLine("-- headers");
    foreach (var (headerKey, headerValue) in context.Response.Headers)
    {
        responseContent.AppendLine($"header = {headerKey}    value = {headerValue}");
    }

    responseContent.AppendLine("-- body");
    responseBody.Position = 0;
    var content = await new StreamReader(responseBody).ReadToEndAsync();
    responseContent.AppendLine($"body = {content}");
    responseBody.Position = 0;
    await responseBody.CopyToAsync(originalResponseBody);
    context.Response.Body = originalResponseBody;

    _logger.LogInformation(responseContent.ToString());
}

private async Task LogRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    var requestContent = new StringBuilder();

    requestContent.AppendLine("=== Request Info ===");
    requestContent.AppendLine($"method = {context.Request.Method.ToUpper()}");
    requestContent.AppendLine($"path = {context.Request.Path}");

    requestContent.AppendLine("-- headers");
    foreach (var (headerKey, headerValue) in context.Request.Headers)
    {
        requestContent.AppendLine($"header = {headerKey}    value = {headerValue}");
    }

    requestContent.AppendLine("-- body");
    context.Request.EnableBuffering();
    var requestReader = new StreamReader(context.Request.Body);
    var content = await requestReader.ReadToEndAsync();
    requestContent.AppendLine($"body = {content}");

    _logger.LogInformation(requestContent.ToString());
    context.Request.Body.Position = 0;
}
```

}